# Flutter Search in Listview from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, dart, search

This is the code to show how I get data from Firebase Realtime Database:

```
List musicList = <Song>[];
  _MusicAppState() {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("${getCurrentUID()}").once().then((dataSnapshot){
      print("Sucessfully loaded the data");
      List tmpList = [];
      dataSnapshot.value.forEach((k,v){
        tmpList.add(v);
      });
      musicList = tmpList;
      setState(() {

      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("Failed to loaded the data");
    });
  }
```

This is the part of I show the musicList in Listview:

```
Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                // List musicList = <Song>[];
                itemCount: musicList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => customListTitle(
                  onTap: () {
                    playMusic(musicList[index]['url']);
                    setState(() {
                      _currentTitle = musicList[index]['title'];
                      _currentSinger = musicList[index]['singer'];
                      _currentCover = musicList[index]['cover'];
                    });
                  },

                  title: musicList[index]['title'],
                  singer: musicList[index]['singer'],
                  cover: musicList[index]['cover'],
                ),
              ),
```

I'm trying to build a few search function but all of them it didn't work.
Here is one of the search functions that I did:

```
Widget buildSearch() => SearchWidget(
    text: query,
    hintText: 'Songs name',
    onChanged: searchSong,
  );
  void searchSong(String query) {
    final songs = musicList.where((song) {
      final titleLower = song.title.toLowerCase();
      final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();
      return titleLower.contains(searchLower);
    }).toList();
    setState(() {
      this.query = query;
      this.musicList = songs;
    });
  }
}
```

This is also my song.dart file:

```
class Song {
  final String title;
  final String singer;
  final String cover;
  final String url;

  const Song({
    required this.title,
    required this.singer,
    required this.cover,
    required this.url,
  });

}
```

Can someone let me know what's wrong of my code? My search function didn't work

Comment: I wondering how you used `song.title` in your last code snippet. The data is in JSON format (there is no parsing).

Comment: @Nicks101 Yea I know the problem is from that line, but  I can't find out how to fix it. Can you help me please?

Comment: Instead of using json directly, [parse](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) the response first, then return it.

Comment: @Nicks101 this is so new to me. Can you please give me an example? It will be perfect if you give me an example of my code. Very appreciate about that

Comment: I don't understand the flow of the app. This is what I think you're doing.
You're getting the data from firebase. Then store it in `musicList` variable. You're somehow getting `query` for filtering the `musicList`. Then you update the `musicList` with the filtered data.
You might want to consider using a different list for filtered data and not changing `musicList`. Also see [searchDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html) that flutter provides. There are many tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: @Nicks101 I just added the file song.dart. That is all the file relate to the search. I know the problem is from the song.title that you mentioned above. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In your first code snippet, you're adding a `v` to `tmpList`. Assuming `v` is the song (in JSON format), change this to dart data type (`Song` class that you mentioned). You'll get a `List<Song>`.

Comment: @Nicks101 I tried so many ways but still didn't work. Can you please give me an example for that?

Comment: Can you share your whole code? Maybe a GitHub repository or something.